# Applying Euclidean Algorithm to find nth value

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Stuck on two questions which I am unsure of how to approach.

Use Euclidean Algorithm to find the $n$ value:

1. $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ expressed as $\text{gcd}(a,b) = \text{gcd}(a_{1},b_{1}) = \text{gcd}(a_{2},b2_{2}) = ... = \text{gcd}(a_{n},0)$. Find the value of n for $\text{gcd}(999,9)$
2. $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ expressed as $\text{gcd}(a,b) = \text{gcd}(a_{1},b_{1}) = \text{gcd}(a_{2},b2_{2}) = ... = \text{gcd}(a_{n},0)$. Find the value of n for $\text{gcd}(27,72)$

I understand how to compute the $\text{gcd}$ by applying Euclidean Algorithm. But I am taken aback when I saw this question which I have no idea how to start. I will appreciate if someone can guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: apply the Euclidean algorithm and count how many steps it takes ($n$)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that method once and stopped at the first step, because when I take 999/9 it gives 111, there are no quotient or remainder in the first step (which I understand the Euclidean Algorithm needs both). For 27/72, the result is 3/8 which I am not sure if I should take the quotient as 1 and continue the Euclidean Algorithm. I will appreciate if you can provide more details. Thanks!

Comment: I agree $\gcd(999,9)=\gcd(9,0)$, so $n=2 $ for that pair; $\gcd(27,72)=\gcd(72,27)=\gcd(27,18)=\gcd(18,9)=\gcd(9,0)$ [$27=0\times72+27, 72=2\times27+18, $ etc.]

Comment: Ah, I understand the $gcd(27,72)$ now! For $gcd(999,9)$, $gcd(999,9)$ is $n = 1$ and $gcd(9,0)$ is $n = 2$? By the way I think my first step for $gcd(999,9)$ is wrong - $999 = 9 * 1 + 111$. Could you enlighten on this? Finally, $gcd(999,9)$ is $n = 2$ and $gcd(27,72)$ is $n = 5$.

Comment: $999=111\times9+0$; if you want further feedback, you could try posting an answer

Answer (score 0):

There are $111$ pairs where $GCD(n,9)=9, 1\le n \le 999$.

There are $3$ pairs where $GCD(n,72)=9, 1\le n \le 27$.